# Hide admin bar by default

Tags: admin-bar

To hide the admin bar for a user, it is possible to toggle off the checkbox 'toolbar' in personal options for each user.

But when a new user is created to the website the checkbox 'toolbar' is always unchecked 
Is there any way to let it be, by default, that the checkbox 'toolbar' in personal options will be checked? Is there any setting (using some kind of code) that it is possible to control this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, there is a code:

```php
// inside functions file
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Comment: Thanks Rimarx, but this doesn't do what I ask, this simple hide admin bar for all users. this make checkbox on or off, unuseful. I'd like to have the checkbox by default off, but I can toggle on (unchecked) when I need for some user.